# Nucleophilic attack by bromine?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

According this scheme the bromine act as a nucleophile and attacks pyrimidinium generating Br+ species? I always thought that Br2 acts solely as electrophile with Br- as by product.

[image]

Comment: I agree it doesn't look right. Perhaps there is an initiation step where $\mathrm{Br^-}$ is created for example by attack of $\ce{SO_3^-}$ on bromine.

Comment: @K_P Only there's no $\ce{SO3-}$ in there, only $\ce{SO3}$ (gas) and $\ce{HSO4-}$.

Comment: @Jan I meant from the pyridinium suflonate that is formed but it was an example. One could think other ways to create some $\ce{Br^-}$ to initiate the reaction. And in any case it is just a suggestion.